# Why can't I load a PySpark RandomForestClassifier model?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I can't load a RandomForestClassificationModel saved by Spark.

Environment: Apache Spark 2.0.1, standalone mode running on a small (4 machine) cluster. No HDFS - everything is saved to local disks.

Build and save model:

```
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", numTrees=50)
model = classifier.fit(train)
result = model.transform(test)
model.write().save("/tmp/models/20161030-RF-topics-cats.model")
```

Later, in a separate program:

```
model = RandomForestClassificationModel.load("/tmp/models/20161029-RF-topics-cats.model")
```

gives:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.load.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for ParquetFormat at /tmp/models/20161029-RF-topics-cats.model/treesMetadata. It must be specified manually;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$16.apply(DataSource.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$16.apply(DataSource.scala:411)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.EnsembleModelReadWrite$.loadImpl(treeModels.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel$RandomForestClassificationModelReader.load(RandomForestClassifier.scala:301
```

I'd note that the same code works when I use a Naive Bayes classifier.

Comment: Do you remember what the problem was, or what the solution was?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson no I don't remember - it was nearly 4 years ago, sorry.

From memory each node had access to a node-local save of the model. Speculating some, I wonder is Spark is checking across nodes to verify the model is the same on each, and errors when it finds they are different. In the JVM there is a `serialVersionUID` that is used for this kind of thing. But as I said this is speculative, I don't know how to fix it, and it is some years since I looked at it.

Comment: The error itself is about the ParquetFormat schema. Maybe there is a way to extract the schema once when *writing* the code, and then apply it when loading?

Answer (score 1):

Saving the model to HDFS, and later reading the model from HDFS might solve your problem.

You have 4 nodes, each node has its own local-disk. 
You are using model.write().save("/temp/xxx")

Later, in a separate program: 
You are using load("/temp/xxx")

Since there are 4 nodes, with 4 different local disks, it isn't clear to me what exactly is being saved (and to which local-disk) during the write.save() operation, and what exactly is being load() and from which local-disk.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that problem. I symlink /tmp/models to persistent storage on each node so that can all access it (ie, so each machine can find the same file in the same place). This works fine for loading feature parquets as DataFrames, or raw CSV data.

Comment: @NickLothian But with the symlink don't the nodes overwrite each others' files? You said it works fine, do you know why?

Comment: These are node local disks, so there is no way for one node to overwrite the files on another node.